# Как спарсить "полностью прокрученную" html страницу?

Tags: python, html, парсер

Когда мы листаем ленту паблика вк или чего-то подобного, она постепенно прогружается. Моя задача спарсить полностью прогруженную страницу (html код). Возможно плохо искал, но в документации к urllib я такого не нашёл. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И не должно такого быть в [urllib](/questions/tagged/urllib). urllib просто дает сделать http запрос и получить ответ. А то, что вы описывали это работа с [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)'ом, что не относится к обязанностям urllib (или [requests](/questions/tagged/requests), или [bs4](/questions/tagged/bs4)).

Вам нужно или посмотреть как формируется [http](/questions/tagged/http) запрос на подгрузку ленты и его повторять http-запросами, или использовать javascript движок. Например, через [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium).

[Делал как-то пример для прокрутки](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/48f2b747bda410b9387f1be5175120fc07aec6f3/selenium__examples/music_yandex_ru/get_all_tracks_playlist/variant_2_with_scroll_optimization.py#L53) яндекс-плейлиста (*не факт, что сейчас оно работает*) и там использовался такой каркас кода:

```
options_headless = Options()
options_headless.add_argument('--headless')

url = ...

driver = None
try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options_headless)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)  # seconds
    driver.get(url)
    print(f'Title: {driver.title!r}')

    time.sleep(5)

    # Конец страницы, пока лента подгружается мы не можем до него добраться
    footer_el = driver.find_element_by_class_name('footer')

    # Move down page to bottom
    y_position = 0
    while True:
        print('y_position:', y_position)
        try:
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(footer_el).perform()
            break
        except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
            y_position += 250
            driver.execute_script(f'window.scrollTo(0, {y_position});')
            time.sleep(1)

    ...
    # Работаем с текущими данными на страницы, после прокрутки

finally:
    if driver:
        driver.quit()
```

Где,

- Прокрутка страницы делается через js-код `window.scrollTo`, который вызываем у браузера через `driver.execute_script(f'window.scrollTo(0, {y_position});')`
- А `headless` нужен, чтобы спрятать страницу

Comment: Подробная настройка selelium описана тут: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/48f2b747bda410b9387f1be5175120fc07aec6f3/selenium__examples/hello_world.py#L18

Comment: спасибо за информацию